# Command+tab, expose and many other functions stop working after screen sharing

Tags: macos, mac, screen-sharing

When I'm away from my office mac I typically login via screen-sharing or VNC from home/another mac.  Lately, after using screen sharing this way, my office mac will have several problems:

- Command+tab and Command+` no longer work
- Expose and other F-key functions no longer work
- ctrl+space to launch Google QSB no longer works

#### Things I have tried to remedy this:

- Restarting the Finder process
- Restarting the Dock process
- Disabling the screensaver

  - Unfortunately, the screensaver still runs...  A connected issue?
- Deleting preference files for Dock/Finder/screensaver etc.

The only thing that seems to work is a restart.  I usually try and avoid that.

#### System details:

- Macbook pro 13"
- OS v10.5.8

Comment: Does killing the screensaver daemon or setting to a different screensaver not help?

Comment: I didn't try setting another screensaver.  I just changed the time to start to 'Never'.  But killing the screensaver daemon does nothing.

Comment: It seems like the new version of Chromium is causing the problem.

Comment: Scratch that... Just had it recur.

Comment: Im stuck with this problem too. Looks like there is no solution

Comment: I will be updating to Snow Leopard on one of my machines.  I'll post if that fixes it.  For some reason though it has been happening less frequently lately.

Comment: Did it disappear with 10.6? If so, maybe answer this question yourself ("was a bug, fixed by upgrading"?) and accept your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has the behavior of using “Command+Tab” when using screen sharing changed in macOS Big Sur (11.1)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1615827/has-the-behavior-of-using-commandtab-when-using-screen-sharing-changed-in-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to figure this out for some time. I think I found something that works. It worked for me just now without having to reboot.

First, go into your ScreenSharing application preferences and write down your settings (there are only a handful). Then quit ScreenSharing.

Next, go into your user directory in the Finder, then navigate to Library -> Preferences. It's important that you do this through your user folder and not through the Library folder that's on the root of your hard drive.

Once in your Preferences folder, delete `com.apple.ScreenSharing.plist` and `com.apple.ScreenSharing.plist.lockfile` (or you can add an arbitrary extension like `.old` to them if you want to play it safe and be able to re-use the old preferences files.

Finally, restart ScreenSharing. Re-enter any adjusted preferences for that application if you had any that you wrote down. Your F-keys, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and other keyboard shortcuts should once again be working.

Hopefully this will fix it for good. I suspect my preferences file was corrupted, and deleting it caused ScreenSharing to create a fresh one. Either way, it's an easier fix than having to reboot, so give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been resolved after upgrading to 10.6.* (not a reinstall, just upgrade)

No indication of what caused it originally.