# Has the behavior of using “Command+Tab” when using screen sharing changed in macOS Big Sur (11.1)?

Tags: macos, screen-sharing, macos-bigsur

This worked like a charm for a year:

On my iMac, click “Share Screen” on my MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina (10.15.7). Whether in fullscreen or not, all the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keystrokes switched between the windows. Had to use the mouse or something else to switch to host windows on the iMac.

Then maybe when running update to macOS Big Sur (11.1) this changed. Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> always switches back to the host instead of switching between screen sharing windows?

The MacBook Pro is still on macOS Catalina for a while.

Comment: So you are opening up screen sharing on your iMac (Big Sur) to connect to your MacBook Pro (Catalina) and before you updated your iMac to Big Sur 11.1 it worked as you describe but then after you updated it changed?

Comment: thanks @Giacomo1968, yes, exactly .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command+tab, expose and many other functions stop working after screen sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/104322/commandtab-expose-and-many-other-functions-stop-working-after-screen-sharing)

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but those who wandered here like me and couldn't find a solution anywhere else, you can go to:

`System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility`

Then you can add the Screen Sharing app which is located in:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications`

Then you should be able to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the target host again.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, this somehow went back to 'normal' .. not sure what changed :-)